# Convert factor ddmmyyyy:ss:mm:hh to ddmmyyyy format in R

Tags: r

I have factor of date format `30APR2019:00:00:00`, how can I convert it to date format `ddmmyy` in R?

Comment: Try `lubridate::dmy_hms("30APR2019:00:00:00")
[1] "2019-04-30 UTC"` and the `format` or `sub(":.*", "","30APR2019:00:00:00")
[1] "30APR2019"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date back you can convert to date-time using `as.POSIXct` and then return date

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("30APR2019:00:00:00", format = "%d%b%Y:%T"))
```

If you want it in the specific format, we can use `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct("30APR2019:00:00:00", format = "%d%b%Y:%T"), "%d%m%Y")
```

Comment: did you tried your codes? I got NA for both of them.

Comment: @GiedriusUrbonas what code did you use? It seems to work for the example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to strip off the substring

```
sub(":.*", "","30APR2019:00:00:00")
#"30APR2019"
```

Or with substring

```
substr("30APR2019:00:00:00", 1, 9)
```

---

Or using `strptime`

```
format( strptime("30APR2019:00:00:00", format = "%d%b%Y:%T"), "%d%b%Y")
#[1] "30Apr2019"
```

Or another option with `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate("30APR2019:00:00:00")
#[1] "2019-04-30"
```

Or with `lubridate` and `format`

```
library(lubridate)
format(dmy_hms("30APR2019:00:00:00"), "%d%b%Y")
#[1] "30Apr2019"
```

and wrap with `format` if needed

Comment: Hi, I tried first and second option, but I got chr format, not Date. How to convert it? For some of your examples I got NA - did you tried them all?

Comment: @GiedriusUrbonas  The `ddmmyyyy` is not `Date` class.  You need `yyyy-mm-dd` without wrapping with the `format`